# Hiding Api key in react-app worked in localhost, but not in heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, api-key

I followed the steps of hiding a Google Api Key by doing the following steps:

1. Create an .env file and put my key in there:

   REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY = my_key
2. Add '.env.local' to my .gitignore file
3. Use it:

   const API_KEY = `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}`

The request I made is through Google geolocation API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${API_KEY}`
```

It works when I'm in localhost, however when I deploy it to heroku then the request to the Google URL does not work, meaning my `API_KEY` does not work when deployed to heroku. Am I messing up some steps, or it takes time for heroku to fully load my environment variables?

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you name your var in heroku exactly as `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY`?

Comment: Did you set your var in Heroku ? https://codeburst.io/accessing-heroku-config-variables-in-your-vue-webpack-app-145afb32dd67

Comment: I would check what the two people above me said, check to make sure you set the variable in heroku correctly, and have it spelled the same way. I would also check to make sure that the heroku URL is "allowed" to make requests to that API. I know the google maps API's sometimes have a whitelist for domains/IP's that can make requests.